# Char Array Formatting

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a hangman game where incorrect letter guesses are stored in a char array called `wrongletters`. Of course, the user begins the game with zero wrongletters, so the `wrongletters` array remains empty upon declaration. The problem I am having is that when I try to display the wrong letters, the letters are spaced very far to the right because of all the other non-value elements in the array

Intended: (Guessed Letters: A B C D)

Current:  (Guessed Letters:        (Extra Spaces)                  A B C D)

Any thoughts? (I am aware game does not function properly yet):

```
void gameSequence()     // Runs the hangman game loop
{
// Local and Global Variable Declaration and Initialization
char guessLetter = ' ';
guessWord = strToUpper(getNextWord());
string maskedWord(guessWord.size(), '_');
char wrongLetters[26] = {};
int numWrongLetters = sizeof(wrongLetters) / sizeof(wrongLetters[0]);

// Input, Process, and Output
cout << "\nLet's PLAY\n\n";
for (int i = 0; i < maskedWord.length(); i++)
    cout << maskedWord[i] << " ";

while (incorrectCount < 6)
{
    drawHangman(incorrectCount);
    cout << "<<<<<<<<<< MAKE A GUESS >>>>>>>>>>\n\n";
    cout << "Guessed Letters: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        cout << wrongLetters[i] << " ";

    cout << "\n\nEnter a letter to guess: ";
    cin >> guessLetter;
    cout << endl;
    guessLetter = toupper(guessLetter);

    for (int i = 0; i < maskedWord.length(); i++)
        cout << maskedWord[i] << " ";

    if (guessWord.find(guessLetter) != string::npos)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maskedWord.length(); i++)
        {
            if (maskedWord[i] == guessLetter)
                maskedWord[i] = guessLetter;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        incorrectCount++;
        wrongLetters[incorrectCount] = guessLetter;
        bubbleSort(wrongLetters, numWrongLetters);
    }
        if (incorrectCount == 6)
        {
            drawHangman(incorrectCount);
            cout << "Sorry you lose - the word was: " << guessWord << endl << endl;
        }
}
incorrectCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use an array. Use a priority queue. This will keep the list nicely sorted and sized.

Comment: @user4581301 This is part of an assignment which specifies that I must use an array, so unfortunately I can't use a priority queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the array `wrongletters` contain at the beginning it of the wrong letters guesed so far. So there is no point of print all of it and especially **sort all of it**.

Hence you should change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < incorrectCount; i++) // incorrectCount replaced 26
    cout << wrongLetters[i] << " ";

...

else
{
    incorrectCount++;
    wrongLetters[incorrectCount] = guessLetter;
    bubbleSort(wrongLetters, incorrectCount+1); // incorrectCount replaced numWrongLetters
}
```

Otherwise when you sort all of the array the spaces go first before the wrong letters.

Comment: I made the changes you recommended, which did fix the spaces problem, but the guessed letters now do not sort correctly. I have tested the `bubblesort()` function and I know it works correctly, so this is not the issue. I can't seem to figure out why the guesses are not sorting correctly anymore...

Comment: @KnightValor maybe you should send `incorrectCount+1` to `bubblesort`?

Comment: Ah good point. That fixed the problem. Thanks a bunch for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Because even if your char sequence is empty, you ask in your loop to display a space after the wrongLetters[i]. Replace the ' ' by endl and you will have
A
B
C
D

Comment: The OP problem is spaces **before** the letters